# Is it possible to create/modify VIEWs with the snowflake Python API?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to create and update VIEWs with the [snowflake library API](https://pypi.org/project/snowflake/0.5.1/) (**NOT** the snowflake-connector-python library)?

In the API docs, I see `kind` in the [signature for the `Table` class](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/reference/latest/_autosummary/snowflake.core.table.Table): `class snowflake.core.table.Table(name: str, kind: str | None = None,`, suggesting this is possible. (A table's "kind" typically refers to whether it is a TABLE or a VIEW.)

However, the `create()` method errors, returning invalid SQL executed by Snowflake. Executed code:

```
    my_view = Table(
        name=MY_VIEW_NAME,
        kind="VIEW"
    )

    root.databases[MY_DB_NAME].schemas[MY_SCHEMA_NAME].tables.create(
        my_view,
        as_select=f"select * from {MY_DB_NAME}.{MY_SCHEMA_NAME}.{MY_TABLE_NAME}"
        )
```

Error - note the extra word "table" in the query `CREATE VIEW table ...`:

```
HTTP response body: {
"error_code": "400", 
"request_id": null, 
"message": 
    "{error: \"001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:\nsyntax error line 1 at position 13 unexpected 'table'.\", 
     details: 
        "{'errno': 1003, 
          'query': 'CREATE VIEW  table TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_VIEW  as select * from test_db.test_schema.test_table', 
          'sqlstate': '42000'
        }"
     }"
}
```

The error suggests that either the kind argument is used for some other purpose or the API's SQL generation is faulty.

Additional supporting evidence for VIEW manipulation not being possible is that listing the table objects in a schema with the code below does not include views that I know exist:

```
tables = root.databases[MY_DB_NAME].schemas[MY_SCHEMA_NAME].tables.iter()
for table_obj in tables:
  print(table_obj.name)
```

The `SchemaResource` class used to list the tables [does not have an analogous `views` attribute](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/reference/latest/_autosummary/snowflake.core.schema.SchemaResource).